# Thread listening to UDP problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp

My program receive some UDP messages, each of them sent with mouse clicks by the client. The program has the main thread (the GUI) only to set some parameters and a second thread create, with

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyFunc, &Data, 0, &ThreadTd);
```

that is listening to UDP packets. 
This is MyFunc:

```
... 
sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))==-1)
  ....
while(true){
bytes_received=recvfrom(sd,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&client_length);
//parsing of the buffer
}
```

In order to prove that there is no packet loss, if I've used a simple script that listen UDP messages sent by my client using a certain port, all the packets sent are received by my computer. 
When I run my application, as soon as the client do the first mouse click, the UDP message is received, but If I try to send other messages (other mouse clicks), the server doesn't receive them (like if he doesn't catch them) and client-side, the user have to click at least 2 times before the server catch the message.
The main thread isn't busy all the time and the second thread parses only the incoming message, enhancing some variables and I haven't assign any priority to the threads.

Any suggetions?

Comment: Can you explain the role threads play in the application.

Comment: There is the main thread (the GUI) that create a second thread that is listening to the udp packets that the client sends him.

Comment: Something odd here.  Every click of the client generates a UDP message - OK.  Every UDP message generated by the client is received by the server - OK.  So, to make things clearer - you click, say, twice on the client and nothing happens. You click a third time and all three messages turn up at once, one after the other, as the thread loops round - is that correct?

Comment: No, I receive only the third message

Comment: How many cores do you have for that application? Do you assign priorities to the threads? Is the main GUI thread busy all the time?

Comment: The main thread is a simple gui where user can set some properties and the other thread loop in a while listening to messages.

Comment: There were three questions, you answered one. Also, I understand, it's Windows, right?

Comment: So.. in my example above, where are the first two messages going?  If there is no message loss, and you only receive the third message, that does not add up?

Comment: I think he is saying that if he just listens to UDP port with some "script" then there's no packet loss, but there *is* packet loss with threaded app.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov OK, if that's the case, need to see more code, as suggested by the other posters.  Running a while loop and recvfrom is just fine, as I'm sure you know.  Done it loads, all messages gratefully received, (well, on local LAN anyway, surely UDP not reliable in general).

Comment: Also, you need to check the return value of recvfrom() for SOCKET_ERROR and, if found, call WSAGetLastError().

Answer (score 2):

in addition to mark's suggestion, you could also use wireshark/netcat to see when/where the datagrams are sent

Comment: As I said before, the problem isn't the packet loss!

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion - find out for sure that the server, and not the client, is causing the problem.

Comment: In fact I think that the server has some issues, maybe the function thread or the socket.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem related to socket programming. I would suggest incorporating a call to `select()` or `epoll()` with the call to `recvfrom()`. This is a more standard approach to socket programming. This way, the UDP server could receive messages from multiple clients, and it wouldnt block indefinitely.

Also, you should isolate if the problem is that the client doesnt always send a packet for every click, or if somehow the server doesnt always receive them. Wireshark could help see when packets are sent.

Comment: But the client is only one, the select() function is used in order to manage multiple clients...

Comment: @Ant4res, that's one use of select(), it will also allow you to block for a certain amount of time, thus allowing you to "simultaneously" process other events on the server.

Comment: I do not need to receive messages from multiple clients (if the thread is blocked indefinitely there is no problem) and, as I've said before, every packets are sent and received from the server, because I've already tested that.

Comment: @Ant4res, ok but if every pkt is sent and received, then I dont understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

not enough info to know why there's packet loss.  is it possible there's a delay in the receive thread before reaching the first recvfrom?  debug tracing might point the way.  i assume also that the struct sockaddr server was filled in with something sane before calling bind()? you're not showing that part...

Comment: The first packet is received nicely, but thereafter the user have to click about 2 times before the server receive the message.

Comment: ok, what else is in that while loop?  what do the recvfrom parameters look like?

Comment: This is my recvfrom: 
`bytes_received=recvfrom(sd,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&client_length);`
Within the loop I parse the buffer and in order to get doubles received.

Comment: the little bit of code you provided looks fine, so we're just playing a guessing game.  one more guess from me: maybe something in your parsing code is overwriting something on the stack and messing up parameters for the next call...

Comment: @mark - maybe, but you would think that, once failed, it would never work again.  Still, it's software, so anything can happen<g>.  You may be right.  TBH, I've got nothin' ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your threaded server app does not receive all the packets when they are sent in quick bursts. One thing you can try is to increase socket receive buffer on the server side, so more data could be queued when your application is not reading it fast enough. See [`setsockopt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use the `SO_RCVBUF` option.